# How to create a new line in the table cell

Tags: latex

I am new to latex, and I am trying to create a table, but the content in the table cell is quite long, so I decided to create a new line for the cells.

But I am not sure how to do that, could someone help me on that? Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multirow table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Observation(Species name)  & Likelihood (Limnodynastes peronii Distribution Model)  &Likelihood (Rhinella marina Distribution Model)\\
  \hline
     Observation 1 (Limnodynastes peronii) &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    Observation 2 (Rhinella marina) &0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fix I made up. The command wraps information in a parbox with a little extra spacing above and below the text to make it look nice. This allows you to limit the width of a cell as well as enter manual line breaks.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multirow table}
\newcommand{\wrap}[1]{\parbox{.33\linewidth}{\vspace{1.5mm}#1\vspace{1mm}}}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
\wrap{Observation\\ (Species name)} &\wrap{Likelihood\\ (Limnodynastes peronii Distribution Model)}  &\wrap{Likelihood\\ (Rhinella marina\\ Distribution Model)}\\
  \hline
     \wrap{Observation 1\\ (Limnodynastes peronii)} &0.0712 &0.2699\\
   \hline
    \wrap{Observation 2\\ (Rhinella marina)}&0.30 &0.013 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Hope this helps- this is my first answer on stackoverflow!